# How to get IP address of sub domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I'm trying to get IP address for host "api.tripadvisor.com" but it is keep changing. I wanted to know how it is possible?

Also how internet domain start with "api". I thought it is always "www" .

Comment: `www` is just a convention for 'world-wide-web. Within limits you can have anything you like. Tripadvisor are probably using a load balancing system to serve different IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got update from Trip advisor that they won't be able to confirm on ip allocated as it is dynamic . best way to debug is based on subdomain and host name

Answer (score 1):

Api is a subdomain for tripadvisor.com, just like for example play.onlinegame.com. I believe you can have many servers for one website and each time you check the ip address you're checking ips of different servers. This would be done to reduce bandwidth on tripadvisor.com. if you can tell us what you need the ip addresses for I could help you further.if you just wanted all of the ips of tripadvisor then i suggest you whois the website multiple times to check all of the ip addresses associated with that website

Comment: we are using API provided by trip Advisor however sometime we are getting connectivity issue . to debug the issue , we need IP address of destination but it is keep changing . Will Trip Advisor will able to confirm list of all possible IP that could be our destination ?

Comment: Why don't you asked that to Trip Advisor?

Comment: Whois the website multiple times, it should come up with the ip addresses